# Kotlin - Conditional ImageView within multiple choice quiz

Tags: android, kotlin

I've created a multiple choice quiz in Kotlin. I've added the ImageView as a parameter in my data class and have tried calling `null` and `image=null` for questions the ImageView is not needed. When I set the ImageView to `android:visibility="gone"` in XML it's hidden for all questions and when set to `android:visibility="invisible"` shows for all questions.

How can I get the ImageView to show for some questions but not all?

XML

```xml
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="@drawable/graph_1"
    android:visibility="gone"/>
```

data class

```kotlin
data class Questions(
    val id: Int,
    val image: Int?,
    val question: String,
    val option1: String,
    val option2: String,
    val option3: String,
    val option4: String,
    val correctAnswer: Int
)
```

Question list

```kotlin
object Constants {
    const val TOTAL_CORRECT: String = "total_correct"
    const val TOTAL_OPP: String = "total_opp"

    fun getQuestions(): ArrayList<Questions> {
        val questionList = ArrayList<Questions>()
        val options = ArrayList<TextView>()

        val q1 = Questions(1, null, "Question 1:", "A", "B", "C", "D", 3)
        val q2 = Questions(2, R.drawable.graph_1, "Question 2:", "A", "B", "C", "D", 2)
        val q3 = Questions(3, R.drawable.graph_2, "Question 3:", "A", "B", "C", "D", 1)
        questionList.addAll(
            listOf(
                q1, q2, q3
            )
        )
        questionList.shuffle()
        return questionList
    }
}
```

Comment: you question is not clear android:visibility="invisble" will never show anything on screen for any questions. can you share code for setvisibility logic also where the actual problem exits

Comment: setvisibility logic is in Questions 2 & 3 when `R.drawable` is called. In XML if I omit `android:visibility`, the image set in XML (R.drawable.graph_1) shows for all questions (regardless if `null` or `image=null` was called or another image was specified (e.g. R.drawable.graph_2))